# how to add a value, in an existing column?

Tags: mysql, insert, field, multiple-columns, insert-update

I have 3 column: (`ToDate`,`FromDate`,`Diff`) .

I want to automatically add a value to `Diff` column with difference between `ToDate` and `FromDate`, and want to save it to table.

I can manually create temp `Diff` column using

`SELECT ToDate,FromDate, (TO_DAYS(FromDate) - TO_DAYS(ToDate)) AS Diff FROM tbl_name`,

But it won't be saved to `Diff` column

So I end up type this :

`INSERT INTO tbl_name (Diff) SELECT (TO_DAYS(FromDate) - TO_DAYS(ToDate)) AS Diff FROM tbl_name`

i want something like this :

```
FromDate  
2018-05-22

ToDate    
2018-05-23

Diff

1
```

Comment: Do you want update an existing row, which doesn't has `DIFF` value inserted, with value of `DIFF` or you want to insert the value of `DIFF` simultaneously with `ToDate` and `FromDate` as a new row

Comment: Because what you're trying to do with `SELECT` statement suggests that you already have records in your table. But the `INSERT` statement suggests that you're trying to insert new records in your table. So what you're actually want to do? Insert new records or Update the existing records.

Comment: thanks. i've tried replace insert with update and thats what i want. sorry for becoming so noob :D

Comment: So you dont have any columns except those 3. I mean a primary `id` or something

Comment: And you want to update a single row or every row in the table?